# Sub query in a inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

Well, in order to get the last entry by date i've done that query :

```
select cle
from ( select cle, clepersonnel, datedebut, row_number() 
over(partition by clepersonnel order by datedebut desc) as rn
        from periodeoccupation) as T 
where rn = 1
```

This one is working and give me the last entry by date, so far i'm ok.

But its the first time i work with subquery and i have to make my query way more complex with multiple joins. But i cannot figure out how to make a subquery in a inner join.

This is what  i try :

```
select personnel.prenom, personnel.nom
from personnel
inner join
( select cle, clepersonnel, datedebut, row_number() 
over(partition by clepersonnel order by datedebut desc) as rn
        from periodeoccupation) as T 
ON personnel.cle = periodeoccupation.clepersonnel
where rn = 1
```

but its not working !

If you have any idea or tips...Thank you !

Comment: the ON statement is wrong. It doesn't know what `periodeoccupation.clepersonnel` is. You have to make that `T.clepersonnel` since you renamed that joined query/table to `T`

Comment: ooh ! Thanks alot ! I've not even noticed that....Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change

```
ON personnel.cle = periodeoccupation.clepersonnel
```

to

```
ON personnel.cle = T.clepersonnel
```

The query join has been aliased with T and you have reference the alias as the table in the aliased query is out of scope in your outer statement.

Comment: Yep ! Thank you for your answer